# Saving objects to binary file to external storage? (Android)

Tags: android, bitmap, storage, external

this is a peace of code I've created to save a "library" of images to external storage in order to use that file in another application. This is a binary file which contains ArrayList of objects.

this is method what makes main job.

```
public void createLib()
{       
    File fl = new File("/mnt/sdcard/imgs");

    File[] rawLib = fl.listFiles();

    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);

    ArrayList<Block> myList = new ArrayList<Block>();

    try{    
        for (int i = 0; i < rawLib.length; i++)
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(rawLib[i]);

            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);

            Block tmpBlock = new Block();

            tmpBlock.bmp = bmp;
            tmpBlock.mozColor = findMidColor(bmp);

            myList.add(tmpBlock);
        }           
       }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {           
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
            myDir.mkdirs();

            File file = new File (myDir, "library.lib");

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

            ObjectOutputStream save = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            save.writeObject(myList);

            save.close();
        }

        catch (Exception exc)
        {
             exc.printStackTrace();
        }
```

here is the class I am working with

```
class Block
{
    Bitmap bmp;
    int mozColor;
}
```

findMidColor() is my method and it work pretty fine, so there is no problem with that.

When I pull created file from the emulators external storage, I see that file's size is about two and a half kilobytes, but original folder with images is about 2-3 megabytes. 
Conslusion is that program saves only pointers to that bmp's. Is there any way to create bynary file of objects which contain images and ints, and reuse that file in another application like a ArrayList or any other array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Bitmap's data (pixels) are not saved in the Bitmap object. They live somewhere in the heap. You are now saving only references to wrong locations.

In your Block class instead of having a `Bitmap` object you can have a path to the `Bitmap` and a method that `returns` a `Bitmap` from that path.

```
class Block{
   String bitmapPath;
   int mozColor;
   Bitmap bmp(){
      //do something here to encode bitmap from file
   }
}
```

You have to save the bitmap to a specific path and store it to `Block.bitmapPath` every time

You can easily find how to save a `Bitmap` to a `File` and retrieve from `File`